# Does adding topics to subscribe to add overhead to communication

Tags: apache-kafka, overhead

Does a publisher-subscribe model from Kafka add a communication overhead when we add topics to subscribe to on the publisher side compared to using no topics to subscribe to but publish messages and let any subscriber receives them without having to subscribe to a certain topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topic names are matched against a regex pattern by the Kafka Controller, after which, the consumer must poll from all leader partitions from all topics it's subscribed to. Yes, there's extra overhead.

Consumers must subscribe, and are not coupled with the producer, so not understanding second part of the question.

Comment: Thank you. If we don't have topics at all, does that mean that all consumers subscribed to a port will get the messages from the producer publishing to that port please?

Comment: Like I said, you must assign or subscribe to a topic. Has nothing to do with ports. You cannot produce without a topic created. And consuming from a non existing topic will throw errors